# Cleaning old solder joints

Tags: soldering, speakers

I'm doing a restoration/repair project on a set of ~50 year old speakers. I've got a lot of fuzziness coming out of the drivers and I suspect it's from the potentiometers, so I snipped them out of the speakers and am going to give them a good treatment with Deoxit.

But I've also noticed the soldered connections are looking quite rough and potentially contributing to the noise. When it comes to electronics I'm an amateur so I was hoping someone might look at these connections and tell me what all the yellow gunk is from, and how I might go about cleaning them up. Scrub down with alcohol? Is desoldering and re-doing the connections the best route? I have some braid but no sucker, although that can change. Any tips much appreciated.

Thanks!
[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

Comment: Deoxit is a joke for this application - Sorry.   Just spraying it in there will dissolve your grease and maybe make them work for a while.  But it won't fix worn tracks.   Old potentimeters (rheostats in this case really) are best renewed by DISASSEMBLY.   You open it up, very very slightly move the wipers such that they are striking fresh virgin tracks.  And DON'T remove the grease...  Reuse if it's still viable.   That solder is still good... if it were bad, you could have just wiggled the wires while operating and you'd hear it.   Little late for that now but....

Comment: Consider just replacing the whole bunch.  What you're looking at are called "L-pads", not "poteniometers" in speaker parlance.  Easy to find and very inexpensive.  Their purpose is to maintain a constant 8-ohm load as seen by the amplifier as you turn them up or down.   Also - frankly - you might not even need them.   They attenuate the volume level  of a given speaker directly --- Useful if a bunch of different speakers are being driven by the same amp as you can tweak each one to have the same apparent volume.  In a modern application with only 2 speakers, you probably don't need this.

Comment: Yellow gunk is very likely rosin flux. These joints actually look fine given how old it is, the only remark is that they have melted the cable insulation a bit, which is mostly cosmetic. But now that you have cut off all the cables you have no other (serious) option but to re-do them.

Comment: @KyleB This info is much appreciated. Having the language ("L-pad") is very helpful. I will try to open up the rheostats and give the wipers some nudging but keep out the Deoxit. I would be open to replacing but I'd like to find something that matches the original specs of the speaker. These controls go from 0db (normal) to -4dB and do not rotate 360°. See this image for the controls: https://img.canuckaudiomart.com/uploads/large/133287-8aa621a9-legendary__sony_ssg7_speakers_for_sale.jpg
And here is an image of the schematic: https://i.imgur.com/qaATC44.jpg

Comment: @Lundin Unfortunately due to the tight enclosure, snipping these out was the only way to remove them without complete disassembly of the cabinets. If the solder joints are fine I would strip, solder, and heat shrink these wires back together, as it seems less risky than re-doing the joints.

Comment: @xxubiqts  Thx for posting the schem and pics.   It's what a figured, there's an L-pad for each speaker.   Gotta be for balancing the drivers.  To an audiophile, those L-pad probably mean the world.  To us normal mortals, I gotta tell you brother --- "4dB" is almost nothing.  You'll barely be able to hear any difference as you rotate that dial.  This might not be worth the chase....   I'm not saying pull the crossover (don't do that!) but I personally wouldn't lose any sleep if both were 'maxed' permanently.  Your amplifier has bass & treble controls?   That'll do pretty much the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yellow/orange bits are most likely flux (rosin) that splatters a bit as a result of heating. If aesthetics are important you can clean it off with alcohol or flux remover, but it isn't negatively affecting anything.

The connections themselves look OK. Solder joints don't typically introduce noise, but there can be [various problems](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-guide-excellent-soldering/common-problems) including cold solder joints, degradation due to oxidation, ones that have failed due to mechanical stress, etc.

If you want to reflow the joints it shouldn't be a problem, but keep in mind you could inadvertently alter a perfectly working joint into a problematic one if, for example, insufficient heat or solder is applied.

Noise is going to be far more likely a result of ~50 year old circuitry than solder joints. Cleaning up 'scratchy' potentiometers is a good idea, but depending on the level of wear, it may be necessary to replace them.

Comment: When you say circuitry, are you referring to anything specifically? Wires, crossover, or just internal speaker parts? Thanks anyways, it was helpful and I'm glad I didn't desolder.

Comment: @xxubiqts I was referring to the amplifier originally, but I realized that your amp may be much newer than the speakers in question. I would still argue that the amplifier (even a nice new class D or something) will introduce more noise than a few good solder joints. To mirror what Kevin and Kyle said in answers/comments, definitely check the mechanics of the speaker and consider replacement of the pots/rheostats/L-pads.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried driving the speakers directly?

Any dirt or metal filings that have been attracted to the speaker magnets could get between the moving coil and the pole-pieces. That could be causing the noises you hear.

Closely inspect them and try to remove any foreign material.